# Accessing a remote COM object via C#

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I have an exe file written using unmanaged C++ which contains a COM object. In order to access it from a managed C# application, I generated an interop assembly. I was able to use this with great success when both apps were running on the same PC.

Now, I have a requirement to make my C# app access the COM object on a remote PC and the existing code gave me some problems. I had to make some small changes e.g.

```
Type ReportItemSetup = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ACME.REPORTITEMSETUP.1", remotePCName);
RpiSetup = (IReportItemSetup)Activator.CreateInstance(ReportItemSetup);
```

became

```
Guid gris = new Guid("{147FF3D1-8A00-11F0-9A6C-0000C099D00B}");
Type ReportItemSetup = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(gris, remotePCName, true);
RpiSetup = (IReportItemSetup)Activator.CreateInstance(ReportItemSetup);
```

This enabled me to get a bit further through the code but then I reached another problem.

I use :

```
REPORTITEMSETUPClass rpis = new REPORTITEMSETUPClass();
```

where REPORTITEMSETUPClass is (edited for brevity)

```
namespace Acme.ReportItemServers.Interop
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FAppObject | TypeLibTypeFlags.FCanCreate | TypeLibTypeFlags.FPreDeclId)]
    [ComConversionLoss]
    [Guid("147FF3D1-8A00-11F0-9A6C-0000C099D00B")]
    public class REPORTITEMSETUPClass : IReportItemSetup, REPORTITEMSETUP, INotifySrc
    {
        public REPORTITEMSETUPClass();

        ... snip ...
        public virtual void INotifySrc_AddUser(INotify pNotify, string bstrUserName);
        ... snip ...
    }
}
```

I need to make a call to AddUser on the INotifySrc interface but the *new* call gives me the error :

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {147FF3D1-8A00-11F0-9A6C-0000C099D00B} failed due to the following error: 
80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

This error is perfectly correct since it is not registered on the local machine.

My question is therefore : is it not possible to use the registration on the remote PC? The Activator.CreateInstance had no problems with the class not being registered locally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must write a serviced component to do this. This involves some COM+ magic and can be quite complex. Look here for a summary: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x7357ez%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I will research this further.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent and then install it in COM+ on the server, then export a COM+ proxy (msi) from the server, and install this proxy on the client.